# Unexpected behavior when calling implicitly declared function

Tags: c

I am learning C and wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a = 2.5;
    say(a);
}

void say(int num)
{
    printf("%u\n", num);
}
```

When I compile this program, the compiler gives following warnings:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:2: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘say’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    6 |  say(a);
      |  ^~~
test.c: At top level:
test.c:9:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘say’
    9 | void say(int num)
      |      ^~~
test.c:6:2: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘say’ was here
    6 |  say(a);
      |  ^~~
```

Running the program unexpectedly leads to a 1 being printed. From my limited understanding, because I did not add a function prototype for the compiler, the compiler implicitly creates one from the function call on line 6, expecting a double as a parameter and warns me about this implicit declaration. But later I define the function with a parameter of type int. The compiler gives me two warnings about the type mismatch.

I expect argument coercion, meaning the double will be converted to an integer. But in that case, the output should be 2, and not a 1. What exactly is going on here?

Comment: `What exactly is going on here?` Undefined behavior

Comment: You are passing a `double` argument to a function that takes an `int` parameter and then printing it as an `unsigned` value. Expect trouble.

Comment: You are right, @TonyTannous, I completely missed that. However using the proper "%d" specifier still prints 1, even using "%ld" a 1 is printed.

My theory was, that in the object code, the double is not converted (because the implicitly created prototype has a double parameter) and the function then reads the bits of the double in memory as an int. But I don't see, how that would be a 1.

I guess this is plain undefined behavior. Still, what exactly would qualify it as that. The implicit creation of the prototype is not UB, neither should argument coercion be in this case.

Comment: Would the UB be from the conflicting prototype vs definition? I just would like to know, what exactly leads to the 1 being printed, UB or not.

Comment: `UB be from the conflicting prototype vs definition?` Well, from https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html it falls into `For a call to a function without a function prototype in scope where the function is not defined with a function prototype, the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion (with certain exceptions)` and `If the function is defined with a type that does not include a prototype, and the types of the arguments after promotion are not compatible with those of the parameters after promotion, the behavior is undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What exactly is going on here?

From the C standard perspective it's undefined behavior.

> What exactly is going on here?

I am assuming you are using `x86_64` architecture. The [psABI-x86_64](https://uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf) standard defines how variables should be passed to functions on that architecture. `double` arguments are passed via `%xmm0` register, and `edi` register is used to pass 1st argument to function.

[Your compiler most probably produces](https://godbolt.org/z/8d5zdx):

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR .LC0[rip]
        movsd   QWORD PTR [rbp-8], xmm0
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        movq    xmm0, rax           ; set xmm0 to the value of double
        mov     eax, 1              ; I guess gcc assumes `int say(double, ...)` for safety
        call    say
        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
say:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi   ; read %edi
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]   
        mov     esi, eax                 ; pass value in %edi as argument to printf
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC1
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        nop
        leave
        ret
```

Ie. `main` set's `%xmm0` to the value of `double`. Yet `say()` reads from `%edi` register that was nowhere set in your code. Because there is some left-over value `1` in `edi`, most probably from crt0 or such, you code prints `1`.

@edit The leftover value actually comes from `main` arguments. It's `int main(int argc, char *argv[])` - because your program is passed no arguments, `argc` is set to `1` by startup code, which means that the leftover value in `%edi` is `1`.

Well, you can for example "manually" set the `%edi` value to some value by calling a function that takes `int` before calling `say`. The following code prints the value that I put in `func()` call.

```
int func(int a) {}    
int main() {
    func(50); // set %edi to 50
    double a = 2.5;
    say(a);
}
void say(int num) {
    printf("%u\n", num); // will print '50', the leftover in %edi
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the explanation I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

> I expect argument coercion

If you had declared the function properly, that's what you'd get. But as you correctly pointed out, you didn't declare the function and got an implicit declaration that takes a `double` as an argument. So when the compiler sees the function call it sees a function call where the argument is a double and the function takes a double. Therefore it has no reason to coerce anything. It just generates the usual code for calling a function with a double as an argument.

> What exactly is going on here?

In terms of the C language, it's undefined behaviour and that's it.

In terms of implementation, what's likely happening is that, as I said, the compiler will generate the usual code for calling a function with a double. On a 64-bit x86 architecture using the usual calling conventions, this will mean putting the value 2.5 into the XMM0 register and then calling the function. The function itself will assume that the argument is an `int`, so it will read its value from the EDI register (or ECX using Microsoft's calling convention), which is the register used to pass the first integer argument. So the argument is written into one register and then read from a totally different register, so you'll get whatever happened to be in that register.

> Still, what exactly would qualify it as [undefined behaviour]?

The fact that you (implicitly) declared the function using one type, but then defined it using another. If the declaration and definition of a function don't match, that causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Would it not convert the double to int? passing 2 to the function?

Comment: @TonyTannous As I said, it has no reason to convert it because, when the function is called, it doesn't know that the function is supposed to take an `int`.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. Any idea if that is the case in C++? since it supports function overloading it will know it takes an int.

Comment: @TonyTannous Implicit declarations are illegal in C++, so the code just won't compile.

Comment: This is what I suspected. Thank you for the explanation and pointing out why exactly this is undefined behavior. This is what I wanted to know. Thanks :)